# Problem passing user defined variables (JMeter Script)

Tags: sql, jmeter, blazemeter, taurus

I don't know how to pass User Defined Variables (from JMeter .jmx Script) on jenkins-taurus.yml (Taurus BlazeMeter configuration file).
It keeps pushing the fixed variables:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/igIK3.png

I need these fields (User Defined Variables) to be blank, and the info inside them to be pushed from the Taurus configuration file:

As you can see, I'm trying to pass the parameters through Taurus configuration file (.yml)
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMpRx.png

SI need to know how to pass these variables inside Taurus script,
should I use `user.{userDefinedParametersHere}` or is there another kind of syntax?

This is necessary because the server URL and login/password could be changed easily this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using incorrect keyword, if you want to populate the [User Defined Variables](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421395-Using-User-Defined-Variables-Using-User-Defined-Variables) via Taurus you should use [`variables`, not `properties`](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#JMeter-Properties-and-Variables)

```
---
execution:
- scenario:
    variables:
      foo: bar
      baz: qux
    script: test.jmx
```

It will create another instances of User Defined Variables called `Variables from Taurus`

If you additionally need to [disable all existing User Defined Variables instances](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Modifications-for-Existing-Scripts) you could do something like:

```
---
execution:
- scenario:
    variables:
      foo: bar
      baz: qux
    script: test.jmx
    #if you want to additionally disable User Defined Variables:
    modifications:
        disable:  # Names of the tree elements to disable
        - User Defined Variables
```

If you have defined your variables at Test Plan level - don't worry, just override them via Taurus and the script will use the "new" values (the ones you supply via `variables` keyword)

Comment: Thanks, that answer was very useful!